# Multiple many-to-many relations SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a table of `events`, `event_date` and `event_category`. I have two many to many relations using `event_to_date` and `event_to_category`.

I'm trying to build a page of events in a category, grouped by date. I can pull events by date or category, but I'm not sure how to then group this by date.

An example of what I'd like, for a given category:

```
21 Feb
Event 1
Event 2

22 Feb
Event 2
Event 3
```

The code to get the events for a caetgory is:

```
SELECT * from event e
INNER JOIN event_to_category etc ON etc.event_id = e.id
WHERE etc.category_id = 53
```

Edited: Table schema below

```
events: id, title, name, desc, archived, body
event_date: id, name
event_category: id, title, desc, active

event_to_date: id, event_id, event_date_id
event_to_category: id, event_id, event_category_id
```

Comment: Can you give us the schema of the tables?

Comment: Without tables schemas is impossible to help you

Comment: Can you tell us which columns reference each other (would just be guessing at join conditions otherwise)? Also what field has the event date? Is event_date_id a date field? In other words what field of what table has the '21 Feb' and '22 Feb'?

Comment: event_to_category and event_to_date tables are extra as you can add category_id and date_id columns to the __event__ table as foreign keys.
This will simplify your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select ed.name, e.title
  from event e
  join event_to_category etc
    on etc.event_id = e.id
  join event_category ec
    on etc.event_category_id = ec.id
  join event_to_date etd
    on e.id = etd.event_id
  join event_date ed
    on etd.event_date_id = ed.id
 where etc.category_id = 53
 order by ed.name
```

I made several assumptions as to which columns refer to one another. I also assumed that the field called "name" on the "event_date" table is what is of interest.

Comment: I think you've made the correct assumptions about which columns refer to one another but this query returns ALL events, not the ones in the category with id = 53?

Comment: @Richard I think I was missing the event_category table (and its join). Please retry with the edited sql

Comment: Cheers, that worked perfectly and it makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to join the other two table and `GROUP BY` date which as far as i understood it should be `name` from `event_date` table

```
SELECT * from event e
INNER JOIN event_to_category etc 
ON etc.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN event_to_date etd
ON e.id = etd.event_id
INNER JOIN event_date ed
ON etd.event_date_id = ed.id
WHERE etc.category_id = 53
GROUP BY ed.name
```